# Use of Lamport's Signature as a primitive

Tags: reference-request

Is [Lamport's One Time Signature](https://wiki.cc.gatech.edu/theory/images/6/6d/Lec13.pdf) used as a primitive to construct any other cryptographic protocols?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a use of Lamport's scheme precisely as Lamport originally published it; however if we include generalizations of the idea (such as Winternitz signatures), then it has been used as the basis of Hash Based Signatures, such as [this proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-huelsing-cfrg-hash-sig-xmss/)

Comment: thanks, this helps.. if i don't get any other answers, i will close the question with this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Two caveats:

1. Lamport itself isn't fundamental; it's just the prototypical example of a one-way signature.
2. A one-way signature isn't a "primitive" any more than an RSA signature is; it might be more accurate to describe it as a "building block".

However, **yes**, one-time signatures are a keystone operation in [Lu, Au, and Zhang's 2019 Linkable Ring Signature](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-36178-2_26.pdf) scheme.

(Ring Signatures allow users to sign a message as an anonymous member of a set of users; Linkable Ring Signatures allow multiple such signatures by the *same* anonymous signer to be shown to be such.)